# How to hide compiler info marks or change problem severity?

Tags: eclipse

Our team is pretty annoyed by these info marks that look like warnings and also cause little 'i' icons on the projects and files.

Considered solutions:

1) If we could, we would just configure the severity of this from info to ignore, but according to this eclipse bug this is not possible:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520287

2) Manually comment the @SuppressWarnings annotation in and out. Not a solution because we cannot do this for tons of generated files that have @SuppressWarnings annotation on the class level (but no unused fields).

3) I couldn't find a "label decoration" that is responsible for displaying the compilation state (none / info / warning /error). Is this possible somehow?

4) Grateful for any other ideas

[image]

[image]

Comment: You get the info markers because the compiler is set to ignore unused code, so `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` does not make sense. So either remove `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` (via search and replace this can be done in a single operation for tons of files) or change the compiler settings of the project (to get warning/errors at locations without `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`).

Comment: @howlger we understand that the annotation does not make sense in that situation. But we don't care and don't want to see a 'warning about something that is supposed to suppress warnings'.

Comment: @howlger manual correction of someting that is all the time automatically generated is not an acceptable solution for us. And we once made a team decision to configure eclipse to ignore warnings about unnecessary `@SuppressWarnings` annotations.

Comment: There is a compiler setting for this team decision: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings: Annotations*** for ***Unused '@SuppressWarnings' token*** choose ***Ignore***.

Comment: Indeed, apologies. I was under the impression that we had this set to 'ignore', but it was on 'warning'. Time for more discussions...

Comment: See also my comment here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520287#c4

Answer (score 0):

Found an acceptable workaround at least for those classes that we generate ourselves: A dummy import of a complete package that is guaranteed to be always available and will trigger an unused warning. This in turn avoids the currently unignorable compiler info marks generated by a potentially unnecessary @SuppressWarnings annotation.

Note that while we do have save actions configured to automatically organize imports, these generated classes are never edited and saved, so the import remains in this form.

[image]